# Create a SQL Server table within a Schema using EntityFramework Code-First?

Tags: sql-server-2008, entity-framework-4.1, database-schema

Is it possible to create, not just a table with EF CodeFirst, but also have the table be part of a schema?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify the schema with data annotations as follows

```
[Table("MyTable", "MySchema")]
public class MyEntity
{

}
```

Or with fluent API

```
modelMoulder.Entity<MyEntity>().ToTable("MyTable", "MySchema");
```